# Navigating from Tabbed page to Content page it hides the tab, but I want that tabbed pages as it is on Content page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have 3 tabbed pages inside the Xamarin forms. Such as Tab1 Tab2 and Tab3.
Inside the Tab1 having the 1 button click on this button click, I am opening the new page.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class MyTabbedpage: TabbedPage
        {
            public MyTabbedpage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }
     private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
           Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage());
            }
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyTabbedpage"
            >
    <ContentPage x:Name="MySchedule" Title="Tab1" Icon="Calender.png">
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Test"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage x:Name="Submission" Title="Tab2">
        <StackLayout>

            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage x:Name="Code" Title="Tab3">

    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage
```

While clicking on the button it navigates me on MyContentPage. at that time my tab page is hidden bcoz I am navigating to the new page. But I want that Tabbed pages as it is on MyContentPage. 
How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, each `Tab` should be wrapped by a `NavigationPage` and `PushAsync` method should be called not on the `TabbedPage` level but on its children level.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyTabbedpage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage x:Name="MySchedule" Icon="Calender.png" Title="Tab1">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage >
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="Test"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyTabbedpage: TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedpage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        await MySchedule.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyContentPage());
}
```

More information about `Hierarchical Navigation` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical).

Comment: do you have its example